# How to apply a patch correctly?

Tags: linux-kernel, patch

I am trying to patch a linux 3.13.7 source tree to 3.13.8 using the `patch-3.13.8.xz` file. Since the patch file is in `xz` format, I used the following command to apply it while in the source tree:

```
unxz -cd ../patch-3.13.8.xz | patch -p1
```

But I receive:

```
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
```

I have checked `man patch` for the `-R` flag and the description makes no sense to me. Can someone please explain what is going on and what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: That just means (probably) that the patch has already been applied. The man page says "If  the  first  hunk  of a patch fails, patch reverses the hunk to see if it can be applied that way.  If it can, you are asked if you want to have the -R option set." In other words, you could apply the patch in reverse.

Comment: So instead of using `unxz -cd ../patch-3.13.8.xz | patch -p1`, I can put it in reverse mode with `unxz -cd ../patch-3.13.8.xz | patch -p1 -R`?

Comment: Well, no. You should investigate why the patch you are applying has already been applied. It's usually a sign something is wrong.

Comment: I have tries answering yes to all `Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]` questions and yet most seem to succeed, but some fail. I haven't actually compiled the source before in this particular tree so I guess it would be Ok to download the new `linux` 3.13.8 source tree anyway.

Comment: Yes, I should have said "why patch thinks the patch has already been applied". Programs can make mistakes.

Comment: `--dry-run` is your friend and you should ALWAYS use it before actually patching.

Comment: @Shadur Is this flag to be used with the `patch` command?

Comment: Yes. Basically, it tells `patch` to do absolutely everything except actually alter the files, so you can see if the patch goes through cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

When patching Linux kernel to the next minor version, you should use incremental patch. For your case, you should patch with `patch-3.13.7-8.xz`. This will patch your kernel source 3.13.7 to 3.13.8.

Answer (score 0):

I think what may have happened is that the patch you had was to take an *older* (pre-3.13.7) version of linux to 3.13.8.  When the patch program was run it found some of the changes to be applied were already present in your 3.13.7 source and raised the warning you saw.  This situation has happened to me before and I saw the same symptoms, which is why I propose it.